# Подскажите как мне проверить модель ML c реальными данными

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

```
from  sklearn import  datasets
iris=datasets.load_iris()

x=iris.data
y=iris.target

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.5)

from sklearn import neighbors
classifier=neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()

classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

predictions=classifier.predict(x_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test,predictions))

# 0.9333333333333333
```

Каким образом мне можно проверить модель, задав ему X - ы, что бы он выдал мне предикт по цветку:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы уже проверили модель в данной строке:

```
predictions=classifier.predict(x_test)
```

и получили массив предсказанных цветков:

```
In [308]: predictions
Out[308]:
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0,
       0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0])
```

чтобы получить соответствующие имена цветков:

```
In [305]: X_test_names = np.take(iris.target_names, predictions)

In [306]: X_test_names
Out[306]:
array(['versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor',
       'versicolor', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica',
       'versicolor', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor',
       'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'setosa',
       'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'virginica', 'setosa'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Допустим у меня есть новые X-ы и я хочу проверить к какому типу
>   цветков он более подходит.
>
> на вход модели задать новые X-ы хотелось бы

```
In [310]: X_new = np.array([[4.8, 3.7, 1.33, 0.11], [6.66, 2.99, 6.123, 2.33]])

In [311]: pred_new = classifier.predict(X_new)

In [312]: pred_new
Out[312]: array([0, 2])

In [313]: np.take(iris.target_names, pred_new)
Out[313]: array(['setosa', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
```

Comment: Допустим  у меня есть новые X-ы и я хочу проверить к какому типу цветков он более подходит.

Comment: на вход модели задать новые X-ы хотелось бы.

Comment: @FaridunIsmoilzoda, и что вам мешает подать на вход `classifier.predict()` новые `X`?

Comment: Не знаю в каком формате написать

Comment: @FaridunIsmoilzoda, дополнил ответ примером...

Comment: Супер, то что нужно. Спасибо!